# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I decided to learn MVC so I am going through this tutorial, http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part2-cs.

I created asp.net mvc3 project and added a controller named HelloWorldController. Added two action methods, Index and Welcome.

When I run application and navigate to http://localhost:XXXXX/HelloWorld or http://localhost:50210/HelloWorld/Welcome

I am getting this JScript error message,

```
  Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
```

with following script in the background. 
[image: Error]

Comment: What does this script come from? You should use feature detection; this is poor code.

Comment: This is auto generated script in the background, I have no clue where it comes from.

Comment: where did you define the variable doc?

Comment: This code does not come from ASP.Net.  You should explore your site to find out where it does come from.

Comment: I have reset IE settings to default and it has fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reset IE settings to default and it has fixed the error. Thanks for the help.